# Help Shrinking Table Size

Tags: html, css, padding

I would like to shrink my table in the right navigation, so that there is no longer any extra spacing to the right. However, whenever I make it any smaller (it is 270px) my Project Type section drops down to a new row. I have a feeling it has something to do with padding, but i'm not sure which padding to change. Let me know if you could help.

Here is my website: http://www.merrimentdesign.com

Comment: Can you please add your code to the question?

Comment: -1 for using tables in a non-semantic manner.

Answer (score 1):

Your `td` "categorycontent" contains 2 divs each at 130px wide (260px total) but you've also specified `padding-left` on the `td` element of 5px.

Thus at the moment unless you change 1 of those dimensions the smallest size you can set is `265px`.

How small were you planning on making it? - can you shrink 1 or both of the div's inside?

Answer (score 1):

How much reworking of the HTML and CSS are you wanting to do? A Table-based layout doesn't give you anywhere near the amount of control that you need really.

The problem may be that the table.categories is set to 268px wide:

```
table.categories {margin-top: 43px; width: 268px;}
```

Or that your list elements have a negative margin of 12px in that table:

```
.categories ul li {margin: 0 0 0 -12px; color: #136376;}
```

Or that the categorycontent td has a left padding of 5px:

```
.categorycontent {padding: 0 0 3px 5px; }
```

Maybe try tinkering with those values a bit and see if you can work it out.